# How can I use the googleJavaFormat to make reflowLongStrings set to a max of 120 chars per line

Tags: java, google-java-format, spotless

I am using the Spotless plugin to format my Java code. However, when I am enabling the reflowLongStrings rule, it breaks lines to be no longer than 80 chars.
Is it possible to change it to 120?

Answer (score 1):

Google java format is not configurable by design ([have a look at this](https://github.com/google/google-java-format/wiki/FAQ#i-just-need-to-configure-it-a-bit-differently-how)) so there is no way for configuring a custom max line width. What you can do is to configure spotless plugin to work with a custom eclipse jdt formatter. [Here](https://github.com/diffplug/spotless/tree/main/plugin-gradle#eclipse-jdt) you can see how this is done in the spotless documentation.

For example, for *gradle* you would have:

```
spotless {
  java {
    eclipse().configFile('custom-config.xml')
  }
}
```

Instead of:

```
spotless {
  java {
    googleJavaFormat()
  }
}
```